# Can not append a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an element with a dynamic id and adding it with another `div`.Here tableHTML contains the code of a table. But when I see my console i see undefined for first one and see an empty `div` like `< div id="data0"> < /div >`
why it is not appending please help

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id',"data"+div_count);
console.log($("#"+"data"+div_count).html());
$("#"+"data"+div_count).html(tableHTML);
console.log(div);
$('#data').append($('#'+"data"+div_count).html());
$('#data').append("<br /> <br />");
```

Comment: From where does `div_count` comes? Show HTML too.

Comment: Thank you very much all. I have got my answer from below. And div_count is a global variable declared out of the scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, use

```
var div = $('<div></div>')
    .prop('id', "data" + div_count)
    .html(tableHTML);

$('#data')
    .append(div)
    .append("<br /> <br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, in order to get DIV element by $, you should append the DIV to the DOM first.
Try this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div'),
    container = document.getElementById('data');
container.appendChild(div);
div.setAttribute('id',"data"+div_count);
console.log($("#"+"data"+div_count).html());
...
```